# Java, Point system for a Yahtzee program

Tags: java

So i am working on a school project and the project is to make a simplified yahtzee program with two of the yahtzee point systems, ex small ladder or three of a kind and so far i have made small ladder (1,2,3,4,5) and big ladder (2,3,4,5,6) to work but i have 2 questions.
 1. How can i make a point system for three of a kind?
 2. A part of the project is to make a category if you dont get one of the implied point systems, ex if you get (1,1,4,5,6) then the user is gonna get the option to choose which number he wants to pick for maximum points. I know i cant explain this very well since im swedish and my english isnt the best. But here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Projekt1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

char fortsatta = 'j';
boolean ja;
do{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Välkommen till Johans Yatzy");
int starta = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Vill du starta spelet?",  "Spela igen",
                                                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,  JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

if(starta == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION ){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Du har nu startat spelet");


int[] tar = new int[5];

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
tar[i] = (int)(Math.random()*6+1);
}

String output = "";
java.util.Arrays.sort(tar);

for (int i = 0; i < tar.length; i++) {
output = output + tar[i] + "\t";
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Du har nu kastat dina tärningar och kasten blev följande: " + output);


if (tar[0] == 1 && tar[1] == 2 && tar[2]==3 && tar[3] == 4 && tar[4] == 5) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Grattis, du fick liten stege som är värt 15 poäng");
}

else if (tar[0] == 2 && tar[1] == 3 && tar[2]==4 && tar[3] ==5 && tar[4] ==6) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Grattis, du fick stor stege som är värt 20 poäng");
}

else{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tärningskastet resulterade i varken liten stege eller stor stege");  
}
}
else if(starta == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Programmet kommer nu att stängas ner");
System.exit(0);
}


String startaom;
startaom = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Vill du spela igen? Skriv J för att spela igen");
fortsatta = startaom.charAt(0); 
}while(fortsatta == 'j');
```

}

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you're only doing a simplified version of Yahtzee, so first, here is the simple way to check for three-of-a-kind:

```
if ((tar[0] == tar[1] && tar[1] == tar[2]) ||
    (tar[1] == tar[2] && tar[2] == tar[3]) ||
    (tar[2] == tar[3] && tar[3] == tar[4])) {
    // found 3 of a kind
}
```

---

For a more full-blown version, there are a lot of points for various combinations of multiple-of-a-kind in the [lower section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahtzee#Lower_section):

- Three-Of-A-Kind
- Four-Of-A-Kind
- Full House (Three-Of-A-Kind + Two-Of-A-Kind)
- Yahtzee (Five-Of-A-Kind)

and for the extended [Yatzy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahtzee#Similar_games) version (not Yahtzee):

- One-Pair (Two-Of-A-Kind)
- Two-Pair (Two-Of-A-Kind + Two-Of-A-Kind)

and for the [upper section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahtzee#Upper_section) you need to count how many of a certain number is present.

So, you should start by doing the counts-by-number:

```
int[] count = new int[6];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    count[tar[i]-1]++;
```

Now find the top two counts:

```
int topIdx1 = 0, topIdx2 = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    if (count[i] > count[topIdx1]) {
        topIdx2 = topIdx1;
        topIdx1 = i;
    } else if (count[i] > count[topIdx2]) {
        topIdx2 = i;
    }
```

Now you can easily find your combination (and the points if doing Yatzy):

```
if (count[topIdx1] == 5) {
    // Yahtzee
} else if (count[topIdx1] == 4) {
    // Four-Of-A-Kind       yatzyPoints = 4*(topIdx1+1)
} else if (count[topIdx1] == 3) {
    if (count[topIdx2] == 2) {
        // Full House       yatzyPoints = 3*(topIdx1+1) + 2*(topIdx2+1)
    } else {
        // Three-Of-A-Kind  yatzyPoints = 3*(topIdx1+1)
    }
} else if (count[topIdx1] == 2) {
    if (count[topIdx2] == 2) {
        // Two-Pair         yatzyPoints = 2*(topIdx1+1) + 2*(topIdx2+1)
    } else {
        // One-Pair         yatzyPoints = 2*(topIdx1+1)
    }
}
```

And for the upper section, the points are easily calculated:

```
points = number * count[number-1]
```

Comment: Tyvm, it all makes sense!

Comment: @JohanFredqvist If you find this answer useful, please click the up-arrow. Same for the answer by Gilbert Le Blanc. You can up-vote both if you want. If you like either of these answers, click the checkmark of the answer you find best, so others can see that the question has been answered to your satisfaction.

Comment: Im sorry i cant give you reputation since i dont have over 15 myself, i didnt know about the check thing tho!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the rules for Swedish Yahtzee are the same as the rules for Yahtzee in the United States.

> How can i make a point system for three of a kind?

I'm assuming you're talking about the lower part of the score sheet.

You write a method that checks if your 5 dice have 3 of the same number, and return the sum of the dice as the score.  Return zero if the 5 dice don't have 3 of the same number.

> A part of the project is to make a category if you don't get one of the implied point systems, ex if you get (1,1,4,5,6) then the user is gonna get the option to choose which number he wants to pick for maximum points.

Now I'm assuming you're talking about the upper part of the score sheet.

You ask the user which category they wish to apply their points to.  You only have to show the categories that have not been previously selected.  The user can choose category 2 or 3, with a score of zero, if they wish.

If you're asking about how a computer should play categories, you calculate the category score that loses the minimum number of points from 3 of a kind.

In your example, category 1 would be the first choice, since you only lose one point.  Category 2 loses 6 points, category 4 loses 8 points, category 3 loses 9 points, category 5 loses 10 points, and category 6 loses 12 points.  As the game progresses, the computer has fewer category choices.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i can now continue working on the project