# How to determine if 3 out of 5 numbers match in java?

Tags: java

I have 5 numbers randomly generated by "dice" which are all 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6. Is there a way I could determine whenever 3 of the 5 generated numbers are all the same(a roll of 4, 4, 4, 5, 2 or a roll of 10, 3, 5, 3, 3 for example)?
I could use a series of nested if statements but is there a simpler way that I'm missing?

Comment: There are 6 numbers not 5 : `10, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6`

Comment: Hint: count how often you got each number.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple algorithm question, and you should understand how to write such an algorithm as well as how it will behave in different situations.

Don't use nested if statements. That will be hard to maintain, especially if the code has to change. Try to create generalized algorithms.

I don't know the requirements of your answer completely, so I'll answer it in two ways.

If ordering **does not** matter:

Create a dictionary of integer to integer. (Java calls this a Map. You can use HashMap in your case.) The key will be the value from the dice (10, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6 in your case), and the value will be the number of times that number has appeared. Then you can just look at each key in the dictionary and see if its value hits your threshold.

Alternatively, you can store all the results in an array, and just loop over the elements in the array and count.

If ordering **does** matter (e.g., you have to get 3 2's in a row):

You'll have to keep an array of the dice roll results, and then you can check after each dice roll if the previous 2 values were the same. Or, you can wait until you have all the rolls and then just check one by one to see if you get 3 in a row.

I haven't put any code down because I don't think that's as instructive. If you need more guidance let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array.  Then look for 3 numbers in a row with the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, I'll do your homework for you.

```
boolean hasTriplets = false;
Arrays.sort(nums); //Your array of random ints
for(int x=1; x<nums.length-1; x++)
    if(nums[x-1] == nums[x] && nums[x] == numx[x+1]) 
    {
        hasTriplets = true;
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
if (Stream.of(4, 4, 4, 5, 2)
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity()))
          .values().stream().mapToInt(List::size)
          .filter(value -> value == 3)
          .count() > 0) {
    System.out.println("found exactly 3 occurrences of one number");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `10` in the question should have been a `1`, it would seem you're rolling five 6-sided dice, and want to find three-of-a-kind for a Yahtzee (or Yatzy) game.

If that is the case, you'll want other combinations detected too, so it would be best to collect count of each value, i.e. how many 1's, 2's, ..., and 6's, then find the highest count (and second highest).

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36065970/5221149) for longer description of how to do that for Yahtzee/Yatzy game.

---

If all you're interested in is three-of-a-kind, and it's ok to sort the values, as other have suggested, you can optimize the search a bit.

Once you sort the list, three-of-a-kind will be one of these combinations:

```
3 3 3 4 5
2 3 3 3 4
1 2 3 3 3
```

As you can see, the middle number is always part of the sequence, so you'll start with that. For the first combination, if the first value is equal to the third value, you don't have to test the second value, since it must be the same (sorted, remember). Same for the last combination.

So you code can be:

```
int[] dice = { 4, 4, 4, 5, 2 };
Arrays.sort(dice);
int candidate = dice[2];
if (dice[0] == candidate || dice[4] == candidate
                         || (dice[1] == candidate && dice[3] == candidate)) {
    System.out.println("Found three-of-a-kind for " + candidate);
}
```